# Not able to run test through ANT

Tags: google-chrome, ant, selenium, junit, webdriver

I have a test class, all the tests of this class runs fine if I run in eclipse. (right click on the file , run as jUnit) but when I am trying to run using Ant Script it fails.

Actually this test is to be run against 2 browsers. This test runs fine against IE Chrome. It runs fine against IE. But test is not able to run against Chrome. I am not sure what's happening.
All the driver related information I have placed under allresources/drivers/ of the project path. And browser profiles i have kept under browserProfiles folder of the project.

I am not sure why tests are not able to be picked up for Chrome.

I have attached test code and the code where I am trying to create webdriver and seldriver in the source code.

```
package com.mytests;

public class MyParamTest {
private MyWrapperForBrowser browser;

@Before
public void setup(){
    b = new MyWrapperForBrowser("chrome");
    b.start();
}

@Test
public void testCURDOnEntity() {
    MyEntity e = new MyEntity(browser);
    Assert.assertTrue(e.createMessage("message", "text"));
    // more business logic..
}
}
```

And source code

```
    package com.mysrc;

import java.util.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;

public class MyWrapperForBrowser {

    private final WebDriver webDriver;
    private WebDriverBackedSelenium selDriver;


public MyWrapperForBrowser(String driver) {
        if (driver.equalsIgnoreCase("IE")
        {
            // create webDriver , selDriver
        }
        else{

       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                    "allresources/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities broserCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        broserCapabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--start-minimized"));
        String url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("browserProfiles/ChromeProfile").getPath()
                .substring(1);
        broserCapabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches",
                Arrays.asList("--user-data-dir=" + url));
        webDriver = new ChromeDriver(broserCapabilities);
        selDriver = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(webDriver, "");
}
}

public void start() {
    webDriver.get(getURL());
    selDriver.windowMaximize();
 }
 }
```

The stack trace which I am getting while running the ANT build is :

```
[junit] java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
[junit]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
[junit]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
[junit]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
[junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getResourceURL(AntClassLoader.java:1028)
[junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.findNextResource(AntClassLoader.java:147)
[junit]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.<init>
```

Here is the build script :

```
<project name="MyProject" default="build-proj" basedir=".">

    <property file="./build.properties" />

    <path id="project.classpath">   
        <fileset dir="resources/drivers">
            <include name="*.*" />
        </fileset>       
    </path>

    <taskdef resource="emma_ant.properties">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="${lib.dir}/emma_ant-2.1.5320.jar" />
            <pathelement path="${lib.dir}/emma-2.1.5320.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <target name="build-proj">
        <antcall target="cleanup" />
        <antcall target="compile" />
        <antcall target="test" />
    </target>

    <target name="cleanup" description="clean up">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
        <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
        <delete dir="${test.report.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${build.src.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${build.test.dir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile" description="compiling all the code">
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.src.dir}" debug="true">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="project.classpath" />
            </classpath>
        </javac>
        <javac srcdir="${test.dir}" destdir="${build.test.dir}" debug="true">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="project.classpath" />
                <path path="${build.src.dir}" />
            </classpath>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="test">
        <junit haltonfailure="false" printsummary="true" fork="true" forkmode="once" >
            <classpath>
                <pathelement path="${src.dir}" />
                <pathelement path="${build.src.dir}" />
                <pathelement path="${build.test.dir}" />
                <pathelement path="${test.data.dir}" />
                <path refid="project.classpath" />
            </classpath>

            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <batchtest todir="${test.report.dir}">
                <fileset dir="${build.test.dir}">
                    <include name="**/*Test.class" />
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: I don't know how you can expect help with an ANT error when you don't show the ANT build file! The error is showing a problem trying to open a zip file, but there's simply not enough information to go on.

Comment: @SteveD sorry I missed it. I have updated the Q with buildscript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably your classpath contains not only .jar files.

The ant task "junit" only likes .jar files (or let's better say [Path like structure](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path), to use an Ant term) in the classpath element.

You could try to use

```
<include name="*.jar" />
```

instead of

```
<include name="*.*" />
```

in your "project.classpath"-fileset.

Comment: Well I tried this also, I have kept *.* as I want all driver informations to be kept as part of the build for running the tests.When I checked on console it says :  Unable to obtain resource from E:\myProject\allResources\drivers\chromedriver.exe: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file.

Comment: Aah, I see that you updated your Ant version to 1.8.x, right? There is [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47593) fixed and you can see now the name of the file that is causing the error.     And this .exe file is exactly the problem: This is not a jar file, not a zip file and not a directory, so it is not an Ant 'path like structure'. That's why you get this error.